# Unable to get right URL in HATEOAS Spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-hateoas

I am trying to use below code for REST API

```
  @GetMapping(produces = { "application/hal+json" }, value = "/topics")
  public CollectionModel<Topic> getAllTopics() {
    List<Topic> topics= topicService.getTopicList();

    for (Topic topic : topics) {
        String topicId = topic.getId();
        Link selfLink = linkTo(TopicController.class).slash(topicId).withSelfRel();
        topic.add(selfLink);

    }

    Link link = linkTo(TopicController.class).withSelfRel();
    CollectionModel<Topic> result = CollectionModel.of(topics, link);
    return result;
}
```

Output I get is below

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "topicList": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "rest api1",
            "description": "REST API1",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080"
    }
}
```

}

Expected URL should be

```
{
  "_embedded": {
        "topicList": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "rest api1",
                "description": "REST API1",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/topics/2"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/topics"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```java
Link link = linkTo(TopicController.class).withSelfRel();
```

to

```java
Link link = linkTo(methodOn(TopicController.class).getAllTopics()).withSelfRel();
```

### Reference

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links.builder.methods